# How to index data using solr from another server?

Tags: solr, connection, solr4

I have some .xml file on window server. And my solr is running on another  ubuntu server.
I want to index these files using solr. How to do this? plz help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataImport tool of SOLR which helps you to easily import an XML from Solr's web interface.

see the example of wikipedia [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)